# Xamarin forms Portable project 'LayoutOptionsConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString' not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a `xamarin.forms` app but I can't debug any of my applications because every time I run the debugger, I got the run succed but this message appears:

[image]

It comes from the `InitializeComponents()` and I can run again the app if I remove all childs from my xaml page, but I get the same error in the next page which opens.

This is the XAML: (So easy that I can't figure out the error..)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myproject.SplashScreen">
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Any idea of the problem? Thanks

**EDIT:**

this is the *output* of the application:

```
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono    ( 4971): 
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono    ( 4971): Unhandled Exception:
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono    ( 4971): System.MissingMethodException: Method 'LayoutOptionsConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString' not found.
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono    ( 4971):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:78a6d746-06e3-4db1-9bc3-6adf844731f4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono    ( 4971):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:78a6d746-06e3-4db1-9bc3-6adf844731f4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono-rt ( 4971): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'LayoutOptionsConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString' not found.
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono-rt ( 4971):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:78a6d746-06e3-4db1-9bc3-6adf844731f4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
04-20 11:35:58.233 E/mono-rt ( 4971):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Object:78a6d746-06e3-4db1-9bc3-6adf844731f4 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new project, with all pages and classes same as before. I don't know why but now the new project is working fine. This is not a solution for the bug, but still a way to make the code working again.

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this helps anybody: I was struggling with this error in Xamarin Forms (same result debugging both Android and Local Windows). Mine I solved by debugging in Windows and checking out the "detail" of the exception.
It actually turned out to be 2 different things, the first one was that I was binding a class through XAML that had no default constructor (just had to make an empty one for serialization) and the second was that I had no "Title" property in the Content page of a MasterDetailPage I was using; which for Xamarin, apparently, is a deadly sin (because of cross-platform code-generation)...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myproject.SplashScreen">
    <StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout> 
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tryed this solution but it didn't work :(

Comment: Well, I don't know why but I created a new project and I copy-pasted all files. now it works fine.. Visual Studio misteries, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! Glad its sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the PCL profile for your Xamarin Forms project has been changed to one that is not compatible. Open your PCL project file with a text editor and find the `<TargetFrameworkProfile>` element. Verify that it is one of the compatible profiles. It should be either "Profile78" or "Profile259" or "Profile111". A few others might also be OK, but these are the main ones that I have seen which work.

Comment: thanks for replying, it is Profile111 in my csproj file